# Titanium/Appcelerator images will not show on Android

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm back with tales of frustrating adventures. This time concerning images on the android side of titanium.

Long story short, I can't get any images to show up for android whatsoever, whether it be a background image or a plain image in an imageView object.

I will provide code I'm trying and keep it extremely small and simple so that it can be easily replicated for all of our testing purposes.

**The Code:**

**Attempt #1 programatically creating view and image:**

index.js

```
var header = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    width: 300,
    image: '/images/header.png',
    width: 300
});

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: Ti.UI.FILL,
    title: 'test',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL
});

win.add(header);

win.open();
```

**Attempt #2 plain jane .xml and .tss styling:**

index.js:

```
$.index.open();
```

index.xml:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <Label id="label">Hello World!!</Label>
        <ImageView id='img1'></ImageView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

index.tss:

```
".container": {
    backgroundColor: 'white'
}

"#img1": {
    width: 300,
    image: '/header.png',
    width: 300,
    top: 0,
    left: 0
}
```

file locations (i copied the same image to 3 different locations to try and get something):

- app/assets/header.png
- app/assets/android/header.png
- app/assets/android/images/header.png

---

**IMPORTANT, What I have tried:**

- using "/images/header.png
- using "images/header.png"
- using "header.png"
- using "/header.png"

Comment: forgot to meantion, the result of executing this is always the white background with my "hello world" label and thats it.

Comment: Have you tried a different image?

Comment: @Shawn good question. Yes I have attempted to use 3 or 4 different images. all of which I have put into the project. I also went out to google and picked a stock png image to try to see if it was me or something. This also didn't work. I have also tried using Ti.FileSystem.getFile to make sure my path is correct, but I'm looking at seeing all my images in the "resources" build folder so I don't think I'm having pathing issues. I also drew a border around the image to see where it would be on the app and I see a border but no image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, in the ImageView property you have mentioned the width twice, so you can remove one declaration and put the height of the image, like 300 (you can put Ti.UI.SIZE to maintain the aspect ratio)

Second, put the images inside `app/asset/android/images/res-<density>` respectively. Replace `<density>` with for example mdpi / hdpi / xhdpi. (you can put this in res-hdpi for testing)

Do a clean build and then check if it is getting reflected or not.

Comment: Also in the screenshot I am seeing View and Label defined in TSS. Can you remove those.

Comment: got this error when I added to res-long-land-hdpi:

Failed to package application:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  libpng error: CgBI: unhandled critical chunk
[ERROR] :  ERROR: Failure processing PNG image /Users/michael.kellogg/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/AndroidStyleTester/build/android/res/drawable-long-land-hdpi/header_271184a1ea.png.....

so I exported the image as .png (some people said re-save in ms paint but im on a mac). The application successfully built this time, but with the same results as shown in this image: 
http://s12.postimg.org/ssui2h2cd/image_error.png

Comment: Change the TSS to this ==> /images/header_new.png. Remove the portion res-long-land-hdpi. For the moment, I would suggest you to keep the header_new.png inside res-hdpi folder too, just for fallback scenario. The folder is not present by looking in the screenshot, so create one named res-hdpi in the same level where the res-long-land-hdpi is present.

Comment: Dude! it worked!! What kinda weird shifty solution was this? haha. I'm going to do some more testing to narrow down what exactly the solution was. I've started by deleting the image from the res-hdpi folder. I think that may have been the key. If it breaks I'll try deleting the image from any other folder and see if it still works with just that one. Thank you so much

Comment: That is good news indeed. Incase you want to understand as to how it works and what is the mapping all about, do let me know, we can discuss.

Comment: how would we discuss it? Also, in your projects do you just have all your images in the res-hdpi folder or something?

Comment: You share your git repro link so that we can discuss there. In my projects I have 4 different set of images for different device densities, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi.

Comment: do you replicate all your project images 4 times and put 1 set in each of those 4 folders?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104667/discussion-between-mike-kellogg-and-soumya).

Comment: could you please edit your answer to reflect that the solution was placing my images in the res-hdpi folder (that i had to create) and using this type of path "/images/filename.png"?

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple!

Alloy example:

Put your image at `app/assets/images` for example `app/assets/images/header.png` .

Now your code is

```
   <ImageView id='img1' image='/images/header.png'  ></ImageView>
```

Or in `.tss` file

```
"#img1": {
    width: 300,
    image: '/images/header.png',
    width: 300,
    top: 0,
    left: 0
}
```

End !

Comment: I added an "images" folder under app/assets/ but this did not work. be my witness sir. you can see the file location in the bottom left and my results from this image:
http://s21.postimg.org/j1tbfl3o7/image_error.png

Comment: this seems like such a simple thing that doesn't work at all for me. Is my android configuration like all wrong or something? Did I accidently download a chinese knock-off of appcelerator?? lol

Answer (score 1):

put your image :
`app/assets/images/header.png`

then access it with

```
<ImageView id='img1' image="/images/header.png"></ImageView>
```

important : try to clean your project first for every changes you made at assets folder before you run the app!

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator I've seen these answers all over stackoverflow and it frustrated me greatly. I'm not sure if there is some major difference in my configuration compared to others or something, but this doesn't work and has NEVER worked for me. I spent an entire day trying to resolve this. The ONLY thing that worked for me, was creating a "res-hdpi" folder "assets->android->images->res-hdpi. when i put my images in this then it worked. This also doesn't seem to be documented in Titanium anywhere. always the same simple answer that didn't help.

Comment: @MikeKellogg Could you create a JIRA ticket with an attached Titanium project, the Titanium SDK version, Android Build Tools and API level you build with and the log of your build process? If you drop the link here, I'd love to dive in and solve this frustrating oddity for you.

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-710 

Titanium SDK Version: 5.2.0.GA
Android SDK: 5.0.1, API build 21
google nexus 10

Comment: Thanks Mike, let's discuss it further there.